# CRITTERCISM_DIR_NAME: No such file or directory

Tags: crash-reports, crittercism

I am using crittercism crash reporting tool . Initially it is working fine , but now it showing error

> CRITTERCISM_DIR_NAME: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This error suggests that the path of the crittercism library placed on your system is not specified. We usually encounter this message while uploading dSYM using the build script. By following this method, we are supposed to mention the APP ID, APP Key and Source path of the script which might be missed here and caused the error. You may refer to the following article for detailed information :

https://docs.apteligent.com/ios/ios_dsym.html#configuring-crash-symbolication